# Converting from MYSQL to MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to convert an old site to use mysqli rather than mysql.

Hit a bit of a stumberling block with this section of code

```
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "")
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysqli_real_escape_string") ? mysqli_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysqli_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;   
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}
```

I keep getting the errors

```
Warning:  mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in 

Warning:  mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in
```

If I add a connection like this

```
$theValue = function_exists("mysqli_real_escape_string") ? mysqli_real_escape_string($test,$theValue) : mysqli_escape_string($test,$theValue);
```

get the error

```
Warning:  mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given



Warning:  mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
```

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong

Many thanks

Comment: The error message tells you *exactly* what is wrong. If you RTM you can see that function takes two parameters. You're only providing one. You're missing your connection.

Comment: You have to pass mysqli handle into functions http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: You don't need to test for `function_exists("mysqli_real_escape_string")`. If mysqli exists, so does `mysqli_real_escape_string`. Just call it.

Comment: Please, FFS, learn to use prepared statements.

Answer (score 6):

Get. Rid. Of. This. Whole. Function.

It should not be used with mysqli ever. Because mysqli has it's own mechanisms that have to be used instead.

However, these mechanisms are quite inconvenient, so, better move towards [PDO **prepared statements**.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

Comment: This is the right answer, get started with PDO and use prepared statements. This will improve code readability and security.

Comment: but mysqli is more faster than PDO

Comment: @Darline oh, please. Does this imaginary difference affect *you* in any particular way?

Answer (score 0):

mysqli_real_escape_string needs to be passed the database connection also.  So you'll need to provide that to the function, then do:

`mysqli_escape_string($connection, $theValue);`

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

In addition, it tells your that your `$test` variable is `null` - again, it's expecting the live database connection you created with `myqli_connect()`.  You will likely need to pass that into the function as a parameter.

Comment: You should not use or link to [w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com). It's not a reliable source of information and we don't want to encourage its use. Not to mention php.net is the definitive source on PHP functions.

Comment: Please read the entire question.